# multiple existing strings in block of data using awk

Tags: unix, awk

i want all dn's (like dn: uid=srinivas) which are having multiple sn: 's using any unix command. My file content is:

```
dn: uid=srinivas
sn: srinivas
sn: srinivas-xxx
sn: xxxxxxxxxxx
cn: srinivas rao g
givenname: srinivas

dn: uid=geetha
sn: geeth
cn: geetha b
givenname: geetha

dn: uid=bhuvana
sn: bhuvana
sn: bhuvana-xxx
cn: xxxxxx
givenname: xxxxxxxxx
```

for above file content, my output should be:

```
dn: uid=srinivas
dn: uid=bhuvana
```

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. I think you are right that awk may be a good tool for this. What awk script have you tried? Please post it and tell how it does not meet your expectations. Be sure to post any error messages that appear.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -v RS= -F'\n' 'gsub(/\nsn:/,"&")>1{print $1}' file
dn: uid=srinivas
dn: uid=bhuvana
```

Comment: thanks it is working fine. but how make sn: search condition as case insensitive.

Comment: `gsub(/\nsn:/,"&",tolower($0))`

Answer (score 0):

another `awk`

```
$ awk '/^dn:/{d=$0;c=0} d&&/^sn:/&&2==++c{print d;d=""} ' file
dn: uid=srinivas
dn: uid=bhuvana
```